# Python linear equation error allowance

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a graph between predicted and actual values which looks like below. Now I need to make linear lines on graph where the error allowance is 20%. ie the points inside the region has 20% error.
Below is my code

```
error_percents = list(((plane_df['Predicted Cost']-plane_df['Actual Cost'])/plane_df['Actual Cost'])*100)
x = list(plane_df['Actual Cost']/100)
y = list(plane_df['Predicted Cost']/100)
max_xy = max(max(x), max(y))
lin_x = np.arange(max_xy)
lin_y = np.arange(max_xy)

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
axes = fig2.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
axes.scatter(x,y,s=100, marker='+')
axes.plot(lin_x, lin_y, c='green', label="zero error")
axes.legend()
```

[image: Graph]

I have the zero error line (x=y) where the error is 0 and how can I form lines for error 20% and plot it ? Please direct me how to approach this problem.

Comment: Please direct me how can I approach this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark the plus/minus 20% region in your plot you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
ys = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
errs = ys * 0.2

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('Actual cost')
plt.ylabel('Predicted cost')
plt.fill_between(xs, ys-errs, ys+errs, label='+-20 percent region', alpha=0.3, color='red')
plt.plot(xs, ys, color='green', label='zero error')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

This results in the following plot:
[image]